# Automatically zoom-to-fit in Visio Web Access ASPX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint-2010, visio

This question is also at [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37588/automatically-zoom-to-fit-in-visio-web-access-aspx) but has failed to get views or responses so I'm posting here.

I'm trying to set the zoom level of a Visio document which is shown through the Visio Web Service.

`http://mysite/_layouts/VisioWebAccess/VisioWebAccess.aspx?id=/Shared%20Documents/MyDiagram.vdw`

I want to use the 'fit to page' zoom level which is achieved by pressing the button on the right of the toolbar. My first thought was click the button via javascript, but didn't get immediate success and also stumbled across MSDN articles on [Objects in the Visio Services JavaScript API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464325.aspx), the [Vwa.VwaControl.getActivePage Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394630.aspx) and the [Vwa.Page.setZoom Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394610.aspx).

I can successfully construct a `VwaControl` object

```
vwaControl = new Vwa.VwaControl("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_VisioWebAccess");
```

but I get `null` when I call `getActivePage()` on this control.

I've tried constructing other `VwaControl` using other ids from the page but none of them are valid - I get an error like "VwaControl does not exist for id {0}". I've tried traversing down the tree from vwaControl._control._zoomControl._fitButton._clickDelegate but I don't know how to fire that delegate.

Has anyone implemented an 'auto zoom to fit' feature in the `VisioWebAccess.aspx` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer at [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/38795/7923) - the zoom and positioning is saved within the document, so set it there. I was unable to control the zoom using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the example on the [getZoom documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394536.aspx), which is to add a handler to 'diagramComplete', you can get a valid reference to the active page...
I.e.

```
function zoomVWAControl()
{

    vwaControl= new Vwa.VwaControl("WebPartWPQ2");  
    vwaControl.addHandler("diagramcomplete", onDiagramComplete);
}

function onDiagramComplete()
{

 try{
        vwaPage = vwaControl.getActivePage();
        var zoomLevel = vwaPage.getZoom();
        vwaPage.setZoom(Number(200));
    }
    catch(err){
        alert(err);
    }
}
```